# 2019-03 latest install of cudnn following tensorflow apt-get Ubuntu 18.04 instructions no longer working. What to try next?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, nvidia

Getting the followig error with Conv1D in keras:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.

Used to work but I purged and updated to latest everything. Have a tried a few times.

Any ideas on what is broken?

EDIT:

not stated explicitly but seems that you should purge all nvidia and cuda and make sure install

sudo apt-get install nvidia-410

and cuda 10-0.

10-1

Comment: I usually don't install the GPU drivers separately. After, purging everything, just install cuda, this will install the drivers as well. Use cuda-10, as that is the version that works with Tensorflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem sometime back. On Jupyter notebook console, I saw the error you mention. In the terminal from where I launched Jupyter, I could see the following message:

*2019-03-24 13:27:14.571966: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:328] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.0.5 but source was compiled with: 7.4.2.  CuDNN library major and minor
 version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version.*

It was because I had cuDNN version 7.0.5 but Tensorflow was built with cuDNN 7.4.2. Upgrading the cuDNN version to 7.5 fixed the problem.

Comment: Intersting, I was trying with 7.5 first. Must be some choppy version conflicts.